# Crash when Setting Up Minecraft 1.12.2 Mod in IntelliJ

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, crash

I'm trying to set up a Minecraft modding environment in IntelliJ. (I've settled for 1.12.2 as this version still by far the largest stable platform for Forge modding with the best support.)

Anyway, I've followed the instruction laid out in the Readme, as well as guides and videos online that date from only a few months ago, so the process should be the same to get a mod set up. However, I'm having an issue actually running the basic "mod" that is shipped with the Forge MDK. The full crash log is below:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----

// My bad.

Time: 12/3/20 8:13 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.flip()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.readImageToBuffer(Minecraft.java:841)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.setWindowIcon(Minecraft.java:680)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:456)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.readImageToBuffer(Minecraft.java:841)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.setWindowIcon(Minecraft.java:680)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:456)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_271, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 358011464 bytes (341 MB) / 785383424 bytes (749 MB) up to 7626293248 bytes (7273 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: 
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    Launched Version: ${MC_VERSION}
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

The only information I can find online is that this error is apparently caused by IntelliJ compiling the mod using Java 1.9. However, this is impossible in my case. The only JDK installed on my machine is version 1.8, which is also what my JAVA_HOME is set to, as well as the only JDK/RE in my PATH. There is no 1.9 JDK to build with. What's causing this, and how do I make it stop? I've checked and I am 100% sure that all compilation through IntelliJ is set to compile with Java 1.8 *ONLY*. Is there an option I've missed?

**Minecraft Version:** 1.12.2
**Forge Version:** 14.23.5.2854 (latest recommended)
**JDK:** 1.8.0_271

I do apologize if my question isn't as clear or concise as it could be. I've been struggling to get this working for almost a month now, and it's really draining me mentally and emotionally. I'm happy to provide more information as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue! It involved deleting the .gradle folder in my User Home, and then re-importing my project (or rather, a new one because I didn't even *have* a project) to rebuild the cached contents of said folder.

I don't know what sort of incorrect stuff was being cached in my User folder, but there was 1.6 GB of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert at this but I'm taking a wild guess. Update your .net run-times. This may not fix anything but I understand the frustration when mods do not work. And will try my best to help those of us who do experience the issues

Comment: As far as I know, those are up to date on my machine. At any rate, both Eclipse and IntelliJ are Java programs themselves, and don't actually run off the .NET framework.